# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)?

Tags: python, django

i am posting javascript localstorage object to backend(django). I am passing it through ajax. 
this is the code in frontend.

```
function checkout_(){

      console.log("checkout");
      for(v in list1){

        object=Object.values(localStorage)[v];

        object = JSON.parse(object)


        }
        //ajax here
        console.log(object.length);
          $.ajax({

                url: '{% url "chout" %}',
                data: {
                   'object': object
                  },
                  method: "POST",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function (data) {
                             alert("success");

                     }
                   });
```

i have given this function to a button via onclick.

```
<button class="bg-danger text-white " onclick="checkout_()">Go To Checkout Counter</button>
```

when i click on this button this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" happens.

in the views.py this is the code.

**views.py**

```
def checkoutnow(request):

    return render(request, "mart/checkout.html")
```

I hope this detail is enough to explain the problem..Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass **csrfmiddlewaretoken** also in the post call because of csrf middleware set in the settings

```
const csrf = "{{ csrf_token }}";
```

and add this key, value pair to your **data**:

```
data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrf, 'object': object },
```

You can skip this and just use **GET** instead of **POST** if feasible.